# Slow startup after replaced SSD

Tags: macos, ssd, startup

Two weeks ago, my SSD had been broken due to the "Invalid node structure" error. I cannot fix it by using `fdisk_hfs`. Then I have to format and re-install, but got another error: "Install Failed: OS X could not be installed on your computer. OS X can't be installed on the disk because a recovery system can't be created. Visit www.apple.com/support/no-recovery to learn more"

Visit that article, then resize the partition and try again but nothing changes.

There is no other way, I have to bring it to the warranty service. They said they replaced my SSD with a new one. But now my Mac boot quite slow:
- 10s from console to Apple logo
- 30s from Apple logo to login window

It used to boot in ~ 11, 12s, the login window seems appear immediatly after Apple logo.

Here're my EtreCheck report:

```
EtreCheck version: 1.9.13 (49)  
Report generated August 29, 2014 at 8:30:05 AM GMT+7

Hardware Information: ?

    MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) (Verified)

    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro11,1

    1 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2 cores

    8 GB RAM



Video Information: ?

    Intel Iris - VRAM: (null)

        Color LCD 2560 x 1600



System Software: ?

    OS X 10.9.4 (13E28) - Uptime: 0 days 0:9:50



Disk Information: ?

    APPLE SSD SM0256F disk0 : (251 GB)

    S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified

        EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted>: 209.7 MB

        Macintosh HD (disk0s2) / [Startup]: 250.14 GB (65.44 GB free)

        Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>: 650 MB



Thunderbolt Information: ?

    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus



Configuration files: ?

    /etc/hosts - Count: 2



Gatekeeper: ?

    Mac App Store and identified developers



Kernel Extensions: ?

    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (4.3.14) Support

    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (4.3.14) Support

    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (4.3.14) Support

    [loaded]    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (4.3.14) Support



Launch Daemons: ?

    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist Support

    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist Support



Launch Agents: ?

    [running]    jp.co.canon.CUPSCAPT.BG.plist Support



User Launch Agents: ?

    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist Support

    [not loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist Support



User Login Items: ?

    Karabiner

    Dropbox



Internet Plug-ins: ?

    FlashPlayer-10.6: Version: 14.0.0.176 - SDK 10.6 Support

    Flash Player: Version: 14.0.0.176 - SDK 10.6 Support

    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3

    Default Browser: Version: 537 - SDK 10.9



Audio Plug-ins: ?

    BluetoothAudioPlugIn: Version: 1.0 - SDK 10.9

    AirPlay: Version: 2.0 - SDK 10.9

    AppleAVBAudio: Version: 203.2 - SDK 10.9

    iSightAudio: Version: 7.7.3 - SDK 10.9



iTunes Plug-ins: ?

    Quartz Composer Visualizer: Version: 1.4 - SDK 10.9



3rd Party Preference Panes: ?

    Flash Player  Support

    Passenger  Support



Time Machine: ?

    Skip System Files: NO

    Mobile backups: OFF

    Auto backup: NO - Auto backup turned off

    Volumes being backed up:

        Macintosh HD: Disk size: 232.96 GB Disk used: 172.02 GB

    Destinations:

        OSX [Local] (Last used)

        Total size: 150.00 GB

        Total number of backups: 7

        Oldest backup: 2014-08-28 17:14:36 +0000

        Last backup: 2014-08-28 23:08:12 +0000

        Size of backup disk: Too small

            Backup size 150.00 GB < (Disk used 172.02 GB X 3)

    Time Machine details may not be accurate.

    All volumes being backed up may not be listed.



Top Processes by CPU: ?

         2%    WindowServer

         1%    fontd

         1%    hidd

         0%    Dropbox

         0%    aosnotifyd



Top Processes by Memory: ?

    303 MB    Google Chrome Helper

    279 MB    Finder

    147 MB    WindowServer

    115 MB    iTerm

    115 MB    Google Chrome



Virtual Memory Information: ?

    2.38 GB    Free RAM

    4.38 GB    Active RAM

    329 MB    Inactive RAM

    941 MB    Wired RAM

    538 MB    Page-ins

    0 B    Page-outs
```

So, I have some questions:

1. Is there any way to make sure that my SSD has been replaced?
2. I would like to know what does it actually do from Apple logo to login window?

---

Found the culprit:

```
Sep  6 07:47:04 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:04 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 8)
Sep  6 07:47:05 MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en0: SSID 'QUANTA' making interface primary (protected network)
Sep  6 07:47:05 MacBook-Pro.local configd[18]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
Sep  6 07:47:05 MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Evaluating
Sep  6 07:47:05 MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: en0: Probing 'QUANTA'
Sep  6 07:47:05 MacBook-Pro.local configd[18]: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.1.102) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
Sep  6 07:47:06 MacBook-Pro.local ntpd[60]: proto: precision = 1.000 usec
Sep  6 07:47:06 MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated
Sep  6 07:47:08 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:08 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 7)
Sep  6 07:47:09 MacBook-Pro.local apsd[98]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
Sep  6 07:47:11 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:11 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 6)
Sep  6 07:47:13 MacBook-Pro.local awacsd[96]: Exiting
Sep  6 07:47:14 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:14 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 5)
Sep  6 07:47:17 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:17 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 4)
Sep  6 07:47:20 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:20 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 3)
Sep  6 07:47:23 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:23 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 2)
Sep  6 07:47:26 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
Sep  6 07:47:26 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Will sleep 3 seconds and try again (retryCount = 1)
Sep  6 07:47:35 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: User info context values set for quanta
Sep  6 07:47:35 MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[345]: Login Window login proceeding
```

The reason is after getting my laptop from the warranty service, I changed the computer name and the user name. So, I guess that I also have to update it in Open Directory (maybe in `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/`), right?

Comment: do you still have to old SSD ?

Comment: You should look in to your Console and report some 50 lines here for us to find out what is it doing at start up.

Comment: @Buscar웃: I have updated my original question. Looks like I have to update Open Directory to match with the new user name. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Glad you found the actual problem, was not the SSD after all. I am not sure, but first try restoring your permissions with disk Utility. The restore your user (you) permissions (the ACL). Boot in Safe mode, that sometimes fixes problems. Do all above before doing anything serious.

Comment: Disk permissions has been repaired. I also tried to boot in Safe Mode, then restart into normal mode. Nothing changes.

Comment: Lets try this in Terminal to fix the mobile account

sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/ManagedClient.app/Contents/Resources/

Comment: then this
"createmobileaccount -n username" then this
"sudo createhomedir -c -u username"

Comment: @Buscar웃: mobile account? Notice that this Mac is not joined to any domain. Why do I need to create a mobile account? I'm sorry, could you please explain more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16969/discussion-between-quanta-and-buscar).

Comment: You have a corrupt Directory Services database. **You are going to have to wipe the drive completely clean and reinstall on a completely blank SSD via internet recovery or a bootable USB installer.** [Follow these instructions.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5441492)

Answer (score 1):

This site works best when using one question at the time, so the answers can be found by others for specific topic, but lets make a exception.

Your problem might be somewhere else (so we need your Console report for that) but to answer your questions:

1- Is there any way to make sure that my SSD has been replaced?

Short of opening the computer and looking at the label on the disk, from outside only way to tell is if you saved the previous UUID and compare it to this SSD in About this Mac.

2- I would like to know what does it actually do from Apple logo to login window?

It starts by finding the boot sector, then it activates the EFI (the boot loader) for OS files, after that it loads the user profile settings and apps.

There is a [very good description here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98319/46541).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved based on this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5582982?start=15&tstart=0

Looks like my OS was installed via Migration Assistant or something like that. So, if you change the Full name in `System Preferences` --> `Users & Groups`, for some reasons, Open Directory still look for the old one. That's the reason why you got:

```
SecurityAgent[345]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.
```

No need to change the Full name back to original. The trick is you can change it in Open Directory first:

- System Preferences
- Users & Groups
- Unlock
- Select user --> Login Options
- Clock "Join" (Network Account Server)
- Open Directory Utility
- Unlock
- Directory Editor
- Search your old Full name
- In the right, click "RealName", then change the value to whatever you want
- Save & Close

Then back to Users & Groups dialog, select your user, then change the Full name to the same value as you have put into Open Directory.

Close and reboot to see what happens.